# How to manage/store luggage for an afternoon in Hong Kong?

Tags: hong-kong, luggage-storage

I contacted the hosts that my girlfriend and I will be staying with in Hong Kong next week, and I discovered that our flight will be getting in several hours before they will be ready for us to check in.

Specifically, our flight gets in at 12, but they will not be ready until 17.

That leaves about 5 hours during which we'll have to cart around or otherwise manage or store our luggage before we will have a place to drop it off.

Are there places/activities we can go to where having luggage with us won't be unmanageable, or is there somewhere (preferably close to the airport) where we can rent storage space for a few hours?

We will each have a medium-sized suitcase (approx. 30cm x 75cm x 1m) and a carry on (backpack).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [store baggage at Hong Kong International Airport](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/passenger/arrival/t1/baggage/left-baggage.html) itself. There's a baggage storage facility at Level 3, Terminal 2. At 10 HKD / hour, it's quite inexpensive too!

Here's something you should consider though: peak time traffic is *bad* in Hong Kong and if you plan to reach your host's house after 5pm, it might take you 1-2 hours by taxi to reach your destination. My suggestion would be relax at the airport - there's [a wide range of dining, shopping, and entertainment options](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/shopping/t2.html) - then take HKIA Express train to the city; the journey is comfortable as there's enough space on the airport express to bring luggage and you'll get into the city faster. After that, it's your choice whether you want to continue travelling on Hong Kong MTR or take a taxi.

Comment: I've used them before and they are great.

Comment: Or instead of the airport, catch a bus to Tung Chung and go for a ride on the cable car. See http://m.np360.com.hk/getting_here

Comment: I love np cable car. Must go for the crystal one. The queue is much shorter.